# Increase class specifity automatically with sass

Tags: css, sass, styles, mixins

I need to increase class specifity of a given class selector.

Example:

```css
.test {
    color: #fff;
}
```

At the moment i need to type .test.test to increase specifity.

Is there another approach to solve this, like a function increase() or some other way of increasing it without appending the same classname?

Comment: always add `not(#radomThingHere)` so you will increase more with ID

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid. I need like an explicit function increase() or override().

Comment: I am not experienced with SASS but my idea was to create that function and this function will autmatically append the `:not(#radomThingHere)` for any class you want

Comment: Assuming a `increase()` function existed as you've descried, how would you expect it to affect your generated CSS? Sass is just a tool to create CSS. If it can't be achieved with CSS, it can't be achieved with Sass.

Comment: I would expect it to add something to the last part of my css selector: Like .my-class:not(false)  => It should add :not(false)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SCSS, then the simplest way (besides forcing it with !important) is to include a parent selector so that it has a higher specificity:

```
.parent {
    .test {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Another method is to target the element as well (if it's always the same type of element). This would also give it a higher specificity.

```
div.test {
    color: #fff;
}
```

If all else fails, you can try moving the code block lower in the SCSS file, since the last selector in the document will win if they have the same specificity. Or, give it the good ol' !important at the end.

```
.test {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: This answer didn´t solve my problem but it gave me some ideas in the right direction. In case someone is using webpack and needs an automated way to increase css specificity: https://github.com/havsar/styleable-loader

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple approaches:
 - You can use `!important`, so that you do not need to repeat class twice. but this is a bad practice.
 - Best way - you can place the class code in the last so that even if the specificity is equal, last one will override previous.
 - you can use parent selector or tag selector, but that makes code dependent on that parent or tag.
 - you can learn more about specificity on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Place your code in the last. that's right solution to your problem

Comment: Unfortunately I can't specify the order (webpack style-loader).

Comment: what all options you have ? editing html or css file ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit lame, I have my own problem with certain react framework that uses style object rather than css/scss/sass. I don't want to override all, I just wanted to override that specific component.

```scss
/** button.module.scss */
.specificButton {
  color: red; /* doesn't work */
}

.specificButton, .specificButton {
  color: red; /* works */
}
```

Now you can use it normally

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './button.module.scss'

const specificButton = () => {
  return (
    <Button className={styles.specificButton}>
      My Beautiful Specific Button made with my SCSS OCD
    </Button>
  )
}
```

Most often you just have to double the css class to increase the specifity. But if it doesn't work, try 3 times. Don't complain to me if you summoned something else.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to increase the specificity automatically, use the [!global](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_variables.php) after the value like this:-

```
.test {
    color: #fff !global;
}
```

this is the way if you want to increase the specificity

Comment: Hey @DarkBee, I appreciate your curiosity! The "!global" rule in SCSS is used to declare a variable in the global scope. It ensures the variable's value is accessible outside its local scope. It's not "!important." Check the SCSS documentation on W3Schools for details: [https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_variables.php, https://www.w3schools.com/sass/showsass.php?filename=demo_sass_var3]. Happy coding!